# Windows development strategy phone tablet desktop

Tags: windows, windows-phone

Shortly we are going to start development of an app that we want to make available for windows phone 7, windows phone 8 & windows 8 (tablet & desktop).

Later we also want to make it available for iPhone & Android phones through the Xamarin products.

I have done quite some windows development in the past, but that is quite some time ago (6 years).

Question 1: What would be the ultimate development strategy to gain as much code re-use as possible targeting all these platforms?

Question 2: What UI framework do I need to choose for the windows versions?

Answer (score 2):

As HellScream suggests, you can use class libraries to share code between different .net applications. You can also use webservices (WCF) and go for a SOA architecture. This could become in handy when moving to IOS/Android development...

As for the UI framework I quess the way to go is XAML with the MVVM pattern. MVVM is a descendant from the MVC design pattern specially designed for XAML. It lets you seperate the UI from the model which could become in handy when creating different views (WP vs windows) on top of the same model.

Comment: Jup, I forgot MVVM, really nice!

Answer (score 1):

**Strategy :** I'm not a WP expert but you can reuse code that you use in Windows 8 & WP8 by using Portable Class Libraries.
It let's you choose what frameworks you want to use in one single class library as in "I'll use Windows RT & Windows Phone 8". By doing that it provides your code for both applications in your solution.
I'm not sure if Windows Phone 7 can do that but you can try that out :)

BUT that can be a bitch as well since some code is supported in WP8 and not in W8 or vice versa which will need a workaround.

Read more on [Cross-Platform Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) & [Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

**UI :** I'd go for XAML because it's just awesome, both WP & W8 support it.
It gives you

Read more on [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx).

**iPhone & Android :** No experience with that, sorry.